# pgfplots separate graph based on one column

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to automatically separate graphs in pgfplots. What I mean by this is something like this: IfI have s file like this as input:

```
x z  y
1 4  1
2 5  1
3 0  2
4 10 2
```

Now I'd like to have the entries with the `1` in one plot and `2` in another plot. Since I want to have this automatically, I'd like to not to this with multiple manual `\addplot`s.

The solution I came up with this up to now, is something like this:

```
\foreach \var in {1,2,..,50}{
  \addplot[y filter/.expression={\thisrow{z}==\var ? y : nan}, unbounded coords=jump] ...
}
```

But this has to cycle about every possible value of `z` which takes very long and is completely unnecessary.
Is there a way to cycle only about the present values or to take the list to cylce about from another file (this would be a fix for me too)?

EDIT:
I solve this now by writing the numbers I want to go through into another file, with `\def\iterate{<numbers>}`, use `\input{...}` in the file that generates the graph and iterate then over the contents of the defined macro. (Not a nice solution, but it works)

Comment: Instead of writing the answer into question, please move it to an answer. And optimaly you would elaborate a bit more and/or provide a full working MWE, so others have it easy to follow/adapt your solution. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, I just see me "solution" only as a quick and dirty fix, so I didn't wanted to make an answer out of this, but if it is wished, I'll do it in the next days ;)

Comment: When you are not satisfied with your solution you could just state it and don't *accept* it. If someone else encounters the same "problem" then there at least is this "dirty fix" which might be better than nothing at all ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well my kind of solution for this was to create a file which contains the declaration of a TeX-macro so that I can include that file into the main latex File and iterate over the declared macro.

Example:

```
File to generate the macro
-------
\def\myMacro{13,31,51,73,92,120}
```

```
\documentclass[multi=page,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

% fileHeader
% pixelCount scaling time

\begin{document}
\input{scales}
\begin{page}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
                        \foreach \var in  \myMacro{
                                \addplot+[red, mark size=2pt, y filter/.expression={\thisrow{rowToFilterFor}==\var ? y : nan}] table[x=column1, y=column2, col sep=space] {inputDataFile.dat}
                        }
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{page}
\end{document}
```

I found this much easier than searching and editing the line where the list to iterate over is declared from the outside (in my case a bash-script) and writing that string to a file isn't that difficult.

PS: And yes this isn't a nice solution, but it works for now, more elegant solutions are always welcome ;)